# Getting Google Sheets Data into Redshift

Tags: python, google-sheets, amazon-redshift, google-api-python-client, google-python-api

I'm trying to get data that lives within a Google Sheet into our Redshift database. I was able to follow the directions from this link: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html

Is it possible to have it pull data from the most recently added google sheets within a folder (instead of just specifying a single sheet) and write to the Redshift table?

Here is what was used to read the google sheets data into Python:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("Copy of Legislators 2017").sheet1

# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/) to [query for files](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#list) added within a given timeframe that are of a specific type. All the search parameters and syntax for such a query are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

```
# Build the Drive service
...

# Query for recent files, with stipulation that their mimetype contains "spreadsheet"
query = "mimeType contains 'spreadsheet' and modifiedTime > '"
query += someDateAsUTC_inRFC_3339_String + "'"

# Execute the query
request = drive.files.list(q=query, .... )
resp = request.execute()
nextPage = resp['nextPageToken']
if resp['files']:
    # Call method to consume files
while nextPage:
    request = drive.files.list_next(request, resp)
    if request:
        resp = request.execute()
        nextPage = resp['nextPageToken']
        if resp['files']:
            # Call method to consume files
    else
        break
# Done
```